# Tom can choose from $4$ soups, $5$ salads and $4$ drinks for his lunch. How many different combinations of a soup, a salad, and a drink can he make?

Tags: combinatorics

Tom can choose from $4$ soups, $5$ salads and $4$ drinks for his lunch.  How many different combinations of a soup, a salad, and a drink can he make?

Any help is appreciated.

Combinations or Permutations?

Comment: Tom should go with French onion, Caesar, and water, and ignore any other combination.  (But see Farzad's answer to see how many combinations he's excluding.)

Comment: @Brendan:  The question was not worded well originally so I clarified it.

Answer (score 2):

if Tom wants one kind of soup with one kind of salad and one kind of drink then he has :

$4$ soups * $5$ salads * $4$ drinks $=$ $80$ different combinations